# Take control over text-decoration: underline without using border property

Tags: html, css

**Ingredients:** just an input tag of type text.

**Question:** How can I control the size, color, position of `text-decoration: underline` styling the input tag?
I saw that `text-decoration-color` is available but only in the `moz` web interpreter and I want something cross-browser like. 
**[EDIT]** I accept JS, CSS, HTML, doesn't matter, but not any workaround: my question is specific, I want control over this specific attribute.

Comment: I suggest you to use `border-bottom` it's more flexible to be styled

Comment: show me your code what did you achieve and what exactly you want ?

Comment: define a class with the border-bottom attr, remove any text-decoration and define any other, textual or css definitions, then span sections and call on your class you wish to have affected.

Comment: Well, it looks like these attributes are limited in functionality and support at this time as I am sure the implementation for text-decoration will expand with further development. 
[Mozilla Developer Network on text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration?v=control)

Comment: Basically, **you can't**. The support for control of the individual properties/attributes you require does not exist as yet.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's an acceptable answer, as you answered my question. Why you're using comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the CSS3 [**text-decoration-color** property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color-property), it works with `Chrome` too.

**Demo:**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: green;
  text-decoration-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is just a link</a>
```

**Note:**

Notice the use of `-webkit-text-decoration-color` to make it compatible with `Chrome`.

You can check **[`text-decoration-color` Cross browser cpompatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration)** for further details about its browser support.

Comment: Because "I saw that text-decoration-color is available but only in the moz web interpreter."

Comment: @BoltClock No this is not true, It just needs 30 seconds to find out that its compatible with Chrome and other browsers too,check my Edit.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way is to remove the text decoration as :

```
text-decoration: none;
```

in your css file and use

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
```

instead of that, you can now change the color and size :)

Answer (score 2):

what if you use

```
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 10px solid black;
```

so you have control over the border properties

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround, but not an answer: I want the control over text-decoration: underline, not adding a border. I know the result is pretty the same, but I'm searching for a specific answer.

Comment: The problem is that using text-decoration-[property] is not cross-browser compatible

Comment: So here's the answer.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Well not supported by all browsers, this is `true` but it's supported by `Firefox`, `Safari` and `Chrome` if we use the `webkit` prefix, check [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration) out, you can see more details on my answer.

Comment: there is not only Safari, chrome and Firefox as web browsers. E.g. there is no support in "Edge" for text-decoration-styles

Answer (score 1):

editing the `text-decoration` like, as you told, the color is possible. but `font-size`, `position` and more is hard. What you could do is instead of using the `text-decoration` is adding on your lets say `<p>` tag a `border-bottom`. Of this border you are able to change size and color. If you want to change the position or other things you should think of maybe adding a `<div>` with a `<style>` to edit all sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
text-decoration-color: #E18728;
```

`text-decoration: underline dotted red;`

Ref links: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-style/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-line/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-color/

Answer (score 0):

**I Hope This example Help You :**

```css
a {

  outline: none;

  text-decoration: none;

  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;

  padding-bottom: 5px;

}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another advanced way to get this done

**HTML**

```
<div class="underline-text"> This is Underlined text </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.underline-text{
      position:relative;
      padding-bottom:5px;
      display:inline-block;
 }

 .underline-text:after{
      position: absoulte;
      bottom: 0px;
      content: " ";
      width:100%;
      background:red;
      height:2px;
      left:0px;
 }
```

Here is codepen.
 https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/QvgeGO

You can do experiments there.

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration` is shorthand property for `text-decoration-color, text-decoration-style` and `text-decoration-line`.

```
syntax{
  text-decoration : text-decoration-line text-decoration-style text-decoration-
  color;
}

a{
  text-decoration : underline red double;
}
```

So you can simple use `text-decoration` or `individually` define `each property`.

**text-decoration-line** - Is a style assigned to element and that can be underline, line-through, overline and such.

**text-decoration-color** - Is a color assigned to element.

**text-decoration-style** - Behaves much like 
border-style, so you could use double, solid, dotted and such property values.

You can read more on this [site](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration).

And for compatibility with browser check on caniuse as some properties are partially supported.

```css
a{
  text-decoration-line:underline;
  text-decoration-color:red;
  text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Text Decoration</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Color and style of text-decoration**

Text decoration is limited in CSS. The [specs in CSS3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp) says you have these settings but actually only firefox supports them:

```
text-decoration-line
text-decoration-style
text-decoration-color
```

**Size of text-decoration**

You have a little bit control of the size of the line with `font-style` attribute. So as you can see it is relative to the font-size.

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#test1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#test2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p id="test1">test 1</p>
<p id="test2">test 2</p>
```

**Position of text-decoration**

There is the attribute `text-underline-position`. But as the other attributes it is mostly [not supported by the major Browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position). So sadly it is not possible to control the position of the text decoration.